# How to solve the "wrong answer" error that isn't an error on visual studio?

Tags: c#

So I wrote a code that works normally on visual studio, but somehow on domJudge it gives the error Wrong answer.

```
int n;
            if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out n))
            if (n > 999)
            {
                return;
            }


        int d;
        if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out d))
            if (d < -99999 || d > 99999)
        {
            return;
        }
        Console.WriteLine(n + " " + d);


        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            int s;
            int e;
            if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out e))                
            if (e + d < -1000000 || e + d > 1000000)
            {
                return;
            }
            s = e + d;
            Console.WriteLine(e + " " + s);

        }
```

So first I got run error and I thought it was because of the string part so changed it to int.tryparse. Unfortunately now I get wrong answer error.

What needs to be changed?

Comment: What inputs are you entering? What outputs do you see along the way?

Comment: If I open it on vs, I type random numbers I want, and I get the output it should be. For example I type 20 and 5, then I can type 20 times different numbers and all numbers are + 5 then. The output is the number you put in and the number + 5

Comment: I phrased that badly. What I meant was - what is DomJudge grading you on? How will it enter the inputs, and what does it expect the outputs to look like?

Comment: Side note - I would use the string formatting methods to write your outputs - `Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", e, s)`. It's a better way to put strings together (versus concatenation).